# How to solve an integral with the use of arcsine

Tags: calculus, integration

The specific question is the following,

$$\int_{-a}^x \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx$$

We are also given that $0\le x\le a$

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: [To avoid the use of horrible notation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Be careful, the upper limit of integration should not be based on the same variable as the variable of integration.

Comment: Hello Michael, This is the question presented to me 100% as it was asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't studied integration by parts or trig substitution, you can do it another way:

$y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ is the equation of the upper half of the circle of radius $a$, centered at the origin. So, to ask for

$\int_{-a}^x \sqrt{a^2-t^2}\,dt$ is the same thing as asking for the area of the region below the circle between $-a$ and $x$, which, if you draw the picture, amounts to computing:

the area of a circular sector: $\frac{1}{2}a^{2}\theta=\frac{1}{2}a^{2}\sin ^{-1}\left ( \frac{x}{a} \right )$

and

the area of a triangle: $\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

Now add these to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\cdot 1dx\;,$$ Now Using Integration by parts, We get

$$\displaystyle I = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\cdot x-\int \frac{d}{dx}\left[\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right]\cdot xdx = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\cdot x-\int \frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\cdot x-\int\frac{(a^2-x^2)-a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\cdot x-I+a^2\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$$

Now Put $x=a\sin \phi\;,$ Then $dx = a\cos \phi d\phi$ in last part of Integral $I$

So $$\displaystyle 2I =\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\cdot x+a^2\int\frac{a\cos \phi}{a\cos \phi}d\phi = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\cdot x+a^2\phi+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\cdot x\cdot \sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\cdot  \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

Now We have to calculate $$\displaystyle \int_{-a}^{x}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx\;,$$ Where $0\leq x\leq a$

So we can write $$\displaystyle \int_{-a}^{x}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx = \int_{-a}^{0}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx+\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$

So ww get $$\displaystyle  = \left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\cdot \sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\cdot \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right]_{-a}^{0}+\left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\cdot \sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\cdot \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right]_{0}^{x}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \int_{-a}^{x}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx = \frac{\pi a^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\cdot \sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\cdot  \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$$

Comment: I've only just started Calculus 2, I was wondering, in the second line:

in the first part, why did you insert the variable "a" into the integral nominator, and subsequently, subtract the first term by I?

Comment: Bcz  Here iam converting $\displaystyle -a^2$ into $(a^2-x^2) = (\sqrt{a^2-x^2})^2$